# Opening a subdirectory using a variable

Tags: python

Hi I currently have some code that extracts some info from various log files, xyz.log, there is also a subdirectory (xyz) that contains another file I want to extract some info from as well. I'm having trouble opening the subdirectory, My current code is like this:

```
for file in log_files:
if file == "1.log":
    linenum = 5
else:
    linenum = 4
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if i == linenum:
            try:
                e = float(line.strip().split()[10])
                xyz = file[:-4]
                #here's where I would like to get the additional data
                    for i, line in enumerate(g):
                        if i == 34:
                            d = float(line.strip().split()[3])
                data.append( (xyz, e, d ))
```

I've tried using a with open with the path set to %xyz/fort.12 but that threw a syntax error I'm guessing the os module is my friend here but I'm pretty naff at using it. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [`os.path.join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join).  It accepts any number of parameters and puts them together using the correct path seperator for whatever operating system that you are on.

```
for file in log_files:
if file == "1.log":
    linenum = 5
else:
    linenum = 4
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if i == linenum:
            try:
                e = float(line.strip().split()[10])
                xyz = file[:-4]
                with open(os.path.join(xyz,'fort.12')) as g:
                    for i, line in enumerate(g):
                        if i == 34:
                            d = float(line.strip().split()[3])
                data.append( (xyz, e, d ))
```